# How can I change wifi static IP address in android with ADB shell?

Tags: android, ip, adb, wifi, settings

My device is based on Android 10 and has been rooted.
I want to find a way of using ADB to change the static IP address of a certain wifi connection and the result should be the same as from the system Settings.

I've tried three ways and none of them worked:

1. `ifconfig wlan0 [ip]`but nothing happened.
2. `ip address add [ip] dev wlan0`the IP in system wifi connection details dose changed but the real IP is still the previous one. It can not change the real IP being used.
3. I've tried to change the `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml` file. But this file will be recovered when I reopen wifi. Changes made on this file will also be invalid.

Comment: I would use inotify tools for Android to check what files are changed when you set a static IP via Android settings. May be the modified files give you more details where and what you have to do to make the change via adb.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```bash
ip address change <IP> dev wlan0
```

Then do `ip address`, in wlan0 you will see the previous IP and then your IP. Do:

```bash
ip address del <old IP> dev wlan0
```

Then you can see your change in `ip address` and `ifconfig`.